# Can Web application hosted on IIS still use Azure App Fabric

Tags: azure

I hosted web app into IIS? Can I still use Azure App Fabric caching services for session? All the samples that I see says first I have to create a web role and then configure app fabric caching service for session mgmt. Is there a way I can configure app fabric caching service for regular web applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use app fabric to monitor wcf and wf workflows and for caching:

here's some useful links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/velocity/threads

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff383731(v=azure.10).aspx

Comment: Those links are for windows app fabric, I want to use azure app fabric caching capabilities..